# Cropping image to square with FineUploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm aware that `FineUploader` has a feature that allows images to be resized.

My goal is to make images square -- as they'll be used as avatars -- and crop the unused portions.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you will need to use a third party library for that

see https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/thumbnails.html#using-a-third-party-library-to-resize-images_1